# Is the sum of IOPS for individual physical disks not equal to the raid0 logical disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid0, iostat

I have a raid0 set up consisting of 2 physical disks:

```
bash-4.2$ lsblk 

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk  
`-xvda1 202:1    0  100G  0 part  /
nvme0n1 259:0    0  1.7T  0 disk  
`-md0     9:0    0  3.5T  0 raid0 /home/ec2-user/deploy
nvme1n1 259:1    0  1.7T  0 disk  
`-md0     9:0    0  3.5T  0 raid0 /home/ec2-user/deploy
```

I created some write load by the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/home/ec2-user/deploy/testfile bs=1024 count=4000000
```

I measured the iostats for md0 and the two physical disks:

```
iostat -d 1
Linux 4.14.154-128.181.amzn2.x86_64 (ip-10-123-151-189.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal)     11/08/2021  _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda              0.50         0.03         3.07     253733   25752714
nvme0n1          96.83         2.76       853.15   23209231 7166198418
nvme1n1          96.66         2.72       851.67   22806490 7153813102
md0             294.30         5.75      1711.15   48271101 14373181088

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
nvme0n1          73.00         0.00       968.00          0        968
nvme1n1          30.00         0.00       268.00          0        268
md0             306.00         0.00      1236.00          0       1236

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
nvme0n1          62.00         0.00       784.00          0        784
nvme1n1          32.00         0.00       756.00          0        756
md0             382.00         0.00      1540.00          0       1540
...
```

I was expecting the tps for `nvme0n1` and `nvme1n1` to sum up to the tps for `md0`.

Is the high difference due to block size difference. Does the physical disk merge multiple writes into a single disk write? Is there a way to confirm that hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`md0`, as a full-fledged block device, has its own scheduler and write merging. So, while `kB_wrtn/s` of each device round up to what reported for the RAID array itself, `tps` is considerably lower due to merging at `md0` level.

To have a better visibility into merging, you can issue `iostat -x -k 1` and look at `wareq-sz` field (or `rareq-sz` for reads).